# Show active item in a navigation bar

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I was building a navigation bar, and wanted the active item to be highlighted (the fontchange to another color). But now the default item is always highlighted, and the active item shows no difference.

My html code is as follows:

```
<div id='fixedbar'>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.html#one"><img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:160px; max-height:160px;"src="images/logo-full-white.png"></a>
        <nav id="fixednav">
            <ul>
                <li class='navitem active'><a href='#home'><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li class='navitem'><a href="#work"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
                <li class='navitem'><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fixedbar ul li.active a{
  color: #ff9933;
}
```

JS:
in the

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

in the body

```
<script>
    $('#fixednav ul li a').click(function(){
    $('a').parent().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    });​  
</script>
```

Comment: A live version can be found here:  http://jsfiddle.net/yujuns/5zZPN/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/CYPL5/1/*

You need to target the `a` not the `li` to make it easy. Also, remember to style the `:visited` as well otherwise that will apply once clicked.

*CSS*:

```
.active {
    color: #ff9933 !important;
}

#fixedbar ul li a, #fixedbar ul li a:visited {
    color: #00f;
}
```

*JS*:

```
$('#fixednav ul li a').click(function () {
    $('#fixednav ul li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Active on click or hover?

If both;

Css

```
#fixedbar ul li.active, #fixedbar ul li:hover{
    background:black; //do what you want to be
}

/* To style just "a" element */

#fixedbar ul li.active a, #fixedbar ul li:hover > a{
    color:red; //do what you want to be
}
```

Js

```
$(function(){
    $('#fixednav ul li a').click(function(){
        $('#fixednav ul').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');

        return false; //return false to aviod scroll top.
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, I want to active on both. But it has the same problem. You can find the live demo based on your correction here. http://jsfiddle.net/yujuns/5zZPN/

Answer (score 0):

For some reason other methods didnt work so I made this its not super efficient so if you can help make it better lmk

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    let me = $('ul li a');
    //using jquery map
    $(me).map(function(idx, elem) {
            console.log($(elem).attr("href"));
              if(url.includes($(elem).attr("href"))){
                    console.log("active");
                    $(elem).addClass("active");
            }else{
            console.log("No");
            }

    });

  }
);
```